# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for "Twelve Days of Christmas" assignment with string arrays

Tags: java, string, indexoutofboundsexception

I was assigned to write a program that'd print the lyrics to "The Twelve Days of Christmas" without using loops (recursion is okay) and I thought I had it but I keep receiving this

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

I've tinkered with my if statements and numbering but a couple friends who I asked and I can't seem to pinpoint the problem.

```
public class TwelveDays{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Twelve_Days(0);
}

public static void Twelve_Days (int day){
    String[] days = {"first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seventh", "eighth", "ninth", "tenth", "eleventh", "twelfth"};

    System.out.println("On the " + days[day] + " day of Christmas my true love game to me ");
    Twelve_Gifts(day);

    day++;
    //if(day <=12);

    if(day < 12){
        Twelve_Days(day);
    }
}

public static void Twelve_Gifts(int n){
    String[] gifts = {"A partridge in a pear tree", "Two turtle doves", "Three French hens",
                      "Four Calling birds", "Five golven rings", "Six geese a-laying",
                      "Seven swans a-swimming", "Eight maids a-milking", "Nine ladies dancing",
                      "Ten lords a-leaping", "Eleven pipers piping", "Twelve drummers drumming"};

    System.out.println(gifts[n]);

    if(n < 12){
        Twelve_Gifts(n-1);
    }
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated of course, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

```
if (n < 12) {
    Twelve_Gifts(n - 1);
}
```

That should be:

```
if (n > 0) {
    Twelve_Gifts(n - 1);
}
```

You're subtracting 1 from `n`, so you want to check that `n` is positive first.

Answer (score 1):

You should put a contion to stop the recursion.

when `n ==0`, you should stop it.

see what will happen when n== 0  for the following code:

```
          if (n < 12) {
            Twelve_Gifts(n - 1);
    }
```

`n - 1 = -1`, then `gifts[n]` becomes `gifts[-1]`, which caused the `Exception`.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

Change

```
public static void Twelve_Gifts(int n) {
```

to

```
public static void Twelve_Gifts(int n) {

    if(n ==0)
    {
        return;
    }
```

and you will avoid the Exception of  `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the Twelve_Gifts method - you are not stopping it from recursing once you have reached the "partridge in a pear tree"